# Как изменить пункты меню верхнего уровня в админке wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

В админке wordpress есть стандартные пункты меню слева, такие как `Записи, Медиафайлы, Страницы, Комментарии и тд`.
Подскажите, как можно поменять стандартное название одного из пунктов?
К примеру мне нужно поменять `Комментарии` на другое название.
Пытался перекомпилировать файл `wp-content\languages\ru_RU.po` с нужным названием для комментариев, но не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файл functions.php:

```
function edit_admin_menus() {
    global $menu;
    global $submenu;

    $menu[5][0] = 'Книги'; // Изменить Записи на Книги
    $submenu['edit.php'][5][0] = 'Все Книги';

}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'edit_admin_menus' );
```

`$menu[5]` - где 5 это id пункта меню. Список всех id:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Эти "пункты", а точнее елементы меню сохраняются в БД.
Для редактирования(сылок, названий) достаточно перейти в панель администрирования, Внешний вид -> Меню. Далее выбрать меню, которое нужно изменить и внести правки к элементам.